# $_SESSION[] inside of Double quotation

Tags: php, variable-substitution

```
$_SESSION['result'] = '2011-08-14 20:34:12';

echo $dateTime = "$_SESSION['result'] +1 hour";
```

Expect output: '2011-08-14 20:34:12 +1 hour'

I know there is error on the double quotation, but don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me out? It would be really appreciate anyone can give some explanation, Thanks!

Comment: If you use a good IDE it should show you blunders like that in the color coding of the code.

Comment: It's good practice to mark your question answered for future Googlers, and will encourage people to answer your future, more confusing questions.

Comment: leave out the single quotes.

Answer (score 4):

```
$_SESSION['result'] = '2011-08-14 20:34:12';

$dateTime = "{$_SESSION['result']} +1 hour";

echo($dateTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$dateTime = "{$_SESSION['result']} +1 hour";
```

or this:

```
$dateTime = $_SESSION['result'] . " +1 hour";
```

and then

```
echo($dateTime);
```

Comment: Yeah ok but at worst you're teaching a PHP noob a bad/confusing practice.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz Bad pratice is different from wrong answer so you should delete all the downvote (because you think they'll not work).

Comment: @Dunhamzzz: the return value of an assignment operation is the value that was assigned, not "true". `$a = $b = $c = 7` is perfectly valid in PHP, and assigns `7` to all 3 vars.

Comment: @MarcB that is not what my original comment was regarding.

Comment: Yes, it was. You were complaining about `echo $dateTime = 'x' . 'y'`, and I'm telling you that this would echo the concatenated string 'xy', not "true", because that's the value that was assigned to dateTime.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the string

```
echo $dateTime = $_SESSION['result']." +1 hour";
```

Comment: Try it, I promise that it works. I am actually having a discussion with a friend about this as I type! `echo $var = 'hi';`

Comment: Yeah but at worst you're teaching a PHP noob a bad/confusing practice.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz Bad pratice is different from wrong answer so you should delete all the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read about [strings in the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). What you want here is called concatenation.

```
$_SESSION['result'] = '2011-08-14 20:34:12';

$dateTime = $_SESSION['result'] . ' +1 hour';

echo $dateTime;
```

Also notice the last line you want to echo `$dateTime` after you have set its contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can find many examples of how to access array elements under [PHP: Array - Array do's and don'ts](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts).

```
$arr = array('foo'=>1234, 'bar'=>array('baz'=>'abcdef'));

// simply no quotes within double-quoted string literals
echo "foo: $arr[foo]\n";
// echo "foo: $arr[bar][baz]\n"; <- doesn't work as intended

// curly-braces -> same syntax as outside of a string literal
echo "foo: {$arr['foo']}\n";
echo "foo: {$arr['bar']['baz']}\n";

// string concatenation
echo "foo: ". $arr['foo'] ."\n";
echo "foo: ". $arr['bar']['baz'] ."\n";

// printf with placeholder in format string
printf("foo: %s\n", $arr['foo']);
printf("foo: %s\n", $arr['bar']['baz']);

// same as printf but it returns the string instead of printing it
$x = sprintf("foo: %s\n", $arr['foo']);
echo $x;
$x = sprintf("foo: %s\n", $arr['bar']['baz']);
echo $x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the single quote for string and nothing for variable, in your case.

```
echo $dateTime = $_SESSION['result'].' +1 hour';
```

Answer (score 0):

> $_SESSION['result'] = '2011-08-14 20:34:12';
>
> echo $dateTime = $_SESSION['result'] . " +1 hour";

Try the above.